# Intellisense not working in VS Code (I'm using Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just downloaded VS Code to use it with Unity, but intellisense is not working at all. All I can get is what I've already written in the file.

I've already tried installing extensions and reinstalling both Unity and VS Code, any help would be appreciated as this is for school.

Answer (score 0):

so what you need to do is in unity head to the top of the unity editor and hit edit then once the dropdown list appears hit preferences. Then next hit external tools and click external script editor, and hit Vs Code or visual studio code.Then close and reopen VScode to make sure it updates

Comment: i have actually tried that already but thanks for the help:)

Comment: Oh do you have the .net framework installed for VS code? bc you need the .net framework for it to work

Comment: how would i do that

Comment: To install The .net framework follow the instructions on this website https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity links are provided for the .net framework here as well

Comment: I am very sorry but that didn't work and yes i did change the omnisharp setting